# Karma tests with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner, eslint, karma-webpack

I am building `js` files by webpack. One of the loader is `eslint`. Whether `eslint` failed a build or not, Karma will try to start tests. Is there any way to prevent it and throw an error once?

Karma config looks like:

```
config.set({
   basePath: '',

   //...
   webpack: {
     module: {
        loaders: [
           {
              test: /\.js/,
              loaders: ['babel', 'eslint']
           }
        ]
        //...
    }
    //...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way, no. Webpack isn't a task runner, loaders are meant to transform source. `eslint` as a loader is sort of doing the linting as a side effect of the loading. I would just do the linting separately from the tests.